# import csv to mysql/sqlite

Tags: mysql, база-данных, парсер, sqlite, csv

Существует некий csv файл

```
geoname_id,locale_code,continent_code,continent_name,country_iso_code,country_name,subdivision_1_iso_code,subdivision_1_name,subdivision_2_iso_code,subdivision_2_name,city_name,metro_code,time_zone,is_in_european_union
333750,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,SN,"Southern Nations, Nationalities, and People's Region",,,Jinka,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
333772,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,OR,Oromiya,,,Jimma,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
333795,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,SO,Somali,,,Jijiga,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
335035,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,HA,"Harari Region",,,Harar,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
336014,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,AM,Amhara,,,Gondar,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
336015,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,AM,Amhara,,,Gonder,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
337405,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,GA,Gambela,,,Gambela,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
337996,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,,,,,,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0
338010,en,AF,Africa,ER,Eritrea,,,,,,,Africa/Asmara,0
```

При попытке импорта в mysql или sqlite3 он ругается на строку `333750,en,AF,Africa,ET,Ethiopia,SN,"Southern Nations, Nationalities, and People's Region",,,Jinka,,Africa/Addis_Ababa,0` из-за несоответствия кол-ва столбцов и разделителей (,) . Подскажите пожалуйста, как всё-таки правильно залить такой файл в эти БД?

Comment: Добавить в шапку (1 строка) еще 1 отсутствующий столбец. Не?

Comment: @Total Pusher какой отсутствующий столбец? Посмотрите внимательно на строку, на которую ругаются БД, там в ковычках куча запятых из-за которых БД думают, что это отдельные столбцы. Таких строк - много, править их не вариант. Мне нужно понять, как объяснить БД (и mysql, и sqlite3), что 100500 запятых в ковычках - это _один_ столбец.
Так что, - не.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';` - так импортируете?

Comment: `IGNORE 1 LINES` забыли ещё. Это в mysql, да. В sqlite3 через `.import file.csv`

Comment: С mysql вроде бы вопрос решён, остался открыт вопрос с sqlite3, нужно что-то типа "ENCLOSED BY" ...

Comment: sqlite3 не работал. но я знаю, что через `jq` можно преобразовать, чтобы `,` заменить на `;` - если это решит проблему, я поищу скрипт

Comment: Да тут не просто заменить один символ на другой надо, тут нужно заменить его везде, кроме того, что находится в `" "` . Я нашёл кучу [советов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963408/change-csv-delimiter-with-sed), но почему-то ни один для меня не работает :( Возникает проблема со строкой `256175,en,EU,Europe,GR,Greece,J,Peloponnese,11,"Nomos Argolidos","Palaia Epidavros",,Europe/Athens,1`

Comment: для меня не имеет значения на какой символ менять, главно сделать это правильно. Почему-то, из всего, что я нашёл, сработало только это `perl -pe 's/(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),/|/g; s/"//g' ` , возможно у меня какие-то проблемы с shell'ом. 
Впрочем, ради интереса готов взглянуть и на Ваш вариант с `jq`.

Comment: с `jq` я ошибся, там не получится "интеллектуальный" разбор. sed возможно использовать для простых вещей. нужна серьезная регулярка, чтобы не попасть на `"..., ..."`

Answer (score 0):

## SQLite

Создаем файл csv-2-dsv.php

```
<?php
while(($data = fgetcsv(STDIN)) !== false) {
  fputcsv(STDOUT, $data, $argv[1] ? $argv[1] : ";", '"');
}
```

Теперь с помощью его конвертируем:

```
cat data.csv | php csv-2-dsv.php ";" > out.csv
```

Последний параметр `";"` - разделитель в выходном файле.

Входим в оболочку SQLite

```
sqlite3 test
```

Выполяем импорт в таблицу `test`

```
.import out.csv test
```

## MySQL

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.csv' INTO TABLE `table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```